# Save to file popup from php script dipping in SQL Database ... no temp files

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a general question, don't know how to go about implementing it

I want to create a link that allows a user to download a file which would be generated from a SQL database.  For example the user enters a ID on an HTML form, click ok and a "save to file" popup would appear.  The data in the file would be from the DB...

I managed to do this via php by saving the file on the tmp directory of the server but I would like to avoid creating files even temporary ones.

Thanks

Comment: What database? Generated how? Without knowing either of those, your question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 0):

You would simply 'pass' the file to the user and the response PHP script would update its header to the file type.

Here is a function from the [header()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#102175) doc @ php.net:

```
<?php
function downloadFile( $fullPath ){

  // Must be fresh start
  if( headers_sent() )
    die('Headers Sent');

  // Required for some browsers
  if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

  // File Exists?
  if( file_exists($fullPath) ){

    // Parse Info / Get Extension
    $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);

    // Determine Content Type
    switch ($ext) {
      case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
      case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break;
      case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break;
      case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break;
      case "xls": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
      case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
      case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
      case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
      case "jpeg":
      case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
      default: $ctype="application/force-download";
    }

    header("Pragma: public"); // required
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers
    header("Content-Type: $ctype");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($fullPath)."\";" );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".$fsize);
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile( $fullPath );

  } else
    die('File Not Found');

}
?>
```

In the above example you would need to modify it to just pass back the data you have, the example above is for files (from your example, like /tmp)

Answer (score 0):

As you're currently saving a temp file as part of the process, I assume what you're doing is reading a BLOB from the database right? Not loading the file from a link which you saved in the database?

In this case I'm guessing you're putting the BLOB into a variable and using `file_put_contents()` to save it to the tmp directory. Then `readfile()` to send it to the browser?

If this is the case then you can actually skip the file write altogether and just `echo` the BLOB straight to the browser.

You just need to send the appropriate headers beforehand. 
Using `header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename: something.ext");` would be enough to download it. You can also send the file's MIME type, e.g. 
`header("Content-type: application/pdf");`

You must also remember some file types are by default opened within the browser. So if you send a header with the pdf MIME type without also sending the content-disposition header, the user will see the pdf in their browser, rather than being prompted to download it.

EDIT: Just putting in a full example, assumes you're using mysql

```
$results = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
  $fileContent = $row['file'];
  $filename = $row['name']
  /* Get MIME type assuming that has 
     been saved with the file in the database
  */
  $mimeType = $row['type'];
}

// optional send mime type header
header("Content-type: $mimeType");

header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename = $filename");
echo $fileContent;
```